# AngularJS keep a temporary value in ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a filter which will generate a random value:

```
function randomize() {
    return function (input) {
        if (input !== null && input !== undefined && input > 1) {
            return Math.floor((Math.random() * input) + 1);
        }
    };
}
```

I have a ng-repeat block in my html:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="config in Configs">
  <td>
      <img src="/images/{{21|randomize}}.png" alt="1">
  </td>
  <td>
      <img src="/images/{{21|randomize}}.png" alt="2">
  </td>
```

From which you can see, picture in the second td block might have different value from the first td block cause it's generating a new random number.

Question is, how can I keep the random number generated from the first td block and reuse it somewhere(eg. second td block) in the same ng-repeat loop?

I only want to keep it for the current loop.

Is there anyway to do this without touching the $scope and JS file? If not, what's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the return value of a filter call to a locally scoped variable. For example

```
  <tr data-ng-repeat="config in Configs">
    <td>{{rand1 = (21|randomize)}}.png</td>
    <td>{{21|randomize}}.png</td>
    <td>{{rand1}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Plunker demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/djnXfH9JOC7wG1yiYIPT?p=preview

Comment: That will make every loop in the ng-repeat hava the same value

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, it won't. but you have to put a pair of parenthesis for 21|randomize. Please modify your answer to ng-init="rand1 = (21|randomize)"

Comment: @CaptainRib yup, forgot the parens. I figured out a better way anyway that avoids `ng-init`

Comment: Should we avoid using ng-init or it's just a personal perference?

Comment: @CaptainRib As indicated in the doco, `ng-init` can be abused. Inline assignment looks neater to me anyway